# chmod - protect users' file being accessed so only owner can access?

Tags: linux, chmod

How to set chmod, so that ONLY owner of the file can read, write and execute?
(other users cannot read, write, and execute)

Comment: Perhaps read the manual page for `chmod` - Quite a simple unix utility

Comment: Interestingly, the spelling and punctuation of this question are identical to some coursework from TU Mombasa.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`chmod 600 filename` will do it;
or
`chmod 700` if it is an executable.

Another way that is less cryptic is:

`chmod go-rwx filename`

- The "g" is for group
- The "o" is for others
- The "-" is for removing permissions
- The "r" is for read-permission
- The "w" is for write-permission
- The "x" is for execute permission.

For the sake of completeness:

- "u" is for user / owner
- "+" is for adding permissions

Comment: Okay. I have read the man for chmod. I understand that by setting 744, I have full ownership and other people will be able to read it too. My webpage can be viewed by others. But I'm really worried that somebody in my school is able to access my folder in linux and copy my source code.

Comment: Whoops, I guess the 744 isn't what you wanted then. The number system has always confused me a bit, which is why I like the notation I showed above. If you use the "go-rwx" that will make sure nobody but you (and the computer admin, but there's no helping that) can read it.

Comment: Here is a good website for figuring out the right number to use:
http://www.onlineconversion.com/html_chmod_calculator.htm

Comment: Thank you~ I have found other web hosting site to put the file on.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following command on the file:

```
chmod 744 filename
```

Comment: I have stored the webpage html file at remote linux school server, and I do not wish people to be able to access the file code. But I want people to be able to see the webpage. Please help!

Comment: @Jeen It needs read permission for the others group or else it can't be served as a webpage.

Comment: I am okay with people able to view the code using file inspector. But I do not wish people to be able to access the file stored in linux university server .

Comment: @Jeen I fixed it, change it to "chmod 744 filename" so others can view it.

Comment: @Greg Can other people in my university able to access my source code store in the linux university server, if I use chmod 744?

Comment: @Jeen any webpage with HTML can be viewed, you can't hide that. The code will always be able to be viewed, because the HTML code is sent to the browser, and then processed. You can't deny people from viewing the HTML.

Comment: back to the question at the top "...How to set chmod, so that ONLY owner of the file can read, write and execute? (other users cannot read, write, and execute) ..."

`chmod 744` is not the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This way all permissions are set to zero, and then the user gets permissions to read the file:

```
chmod a=,u=r file
```

Example:

```
touch file

chmod a=,u=r file

LANG=C stat file
```

```
  File: file
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 29812993    Links: 1
Access: (0400/-r--------)  Uid: ( 1000/ guettli)   Gid: ( 1000/ guettli)
Access: 2023-04-27 13:21:19.034135401 +0200
Modify: 2023-04-27 13:21:19.034135401 +0200
Change: 2023-04-27 13:21:27.458108021 +0200
 Birth: 2023-04-27 13:21:19.034135401 +0200
```