# Folders protection

Tags: ssh, chmod

I need to protect my data in my home on cluster (ssh) by others. 
I would like via chmod to prevent others to enter (read and write) in that directory so that I only have permissions to enter, read and write files. 
Which is the best "chmod" combination to do this? I'm not able to 
do "sudo" and other admin instructions since I'm a simple user of the machine. I already made the folder hidden in this way: ./myfolder but to me is not sufficient 
since via ls -a it is visible.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chmod - protect users' file being accessed so only owner can access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886936/chmod-protect-users-file-being-accessed-so-only-owner-can-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need something like

```
chmod -R u+rw,go-rwX ~
```

Or

```
chmod -R 600 ~
```

which will give you read and write permissions but deny them to other users. Beware, however, that the root user can still access everything.

Visit [this](https://superuser.com/questions/91935/how-to-chmod-all-directories-except-files-recursively/91938#91938) post on superuser. You will find all you need to know. Visit [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) and [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_04.html) to learn more about `chmod` and file security. But was there really a need to ask this question here? [Possible duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886936/chmod-protect-users-file-being-accessed-so-only-owner-can-access?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)